# Find the balance of transaction of each customer starting after last zero balance to latest balance

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I am using SQL Server 2005. I have a two tables -

```
1. tbl_Customer  
  - CustId INT,  
  - Name VARCHAR(40)  
2. tbl_Transaction  
  - TransId INT,  
  - CustId INT,  
  - TranDate DATETIME  
  - DebitAmount NUMERIC(8,2),  
  - CreditAmount NUMERIC(8,2)
```

Data of **tbl_Customer**

```
CustId    Name

1        ST  
2        JS  
3        MA
```

Data of **tbl_Transaction**

```
TransId CustId  Tdate       DtAmt   CrAmt
101     1       1/1/2012    250     100
102     1       1/2/2012    0       100
103     1       1/2/2012    0       50
104     2       1/2/2012    400     200
105     2       1/3/2012    0       150
106     2       1/3/2012    0       40
107     2       1/4/2012    0       10
108     1       1/1/2012    350     50
109     1       1/2/2012    0       200
110     1       1/2/2012    0       100
111     2       1/10/2012   500     300
112     2       1/10/2012   0       120
```

I want to find balance of each customer starting from last zero balance. A balance is (DebitAmount - CreditAmount) for first row and then (Balance - CreditAmount) for next rows. So after the query the result should look like this -

```
TransId CustId  Transdate   DtAmt   CrAmt      Balance
108     1       1/1/2012    350     50      300
109     1       1/2/2012    0       200     100
110     1       1/2/2012    0       100     0
111     2       1/10/2012   500     300     200
112     2       1/11/2012   0       120     80
```

Now main thing is, I want to search customers and display latest balance of each customer in result. If there is no balance (no transaction is available in tbl_transaction), the balance should be null. So the final result should look like this.

```
CustId  Name    Balance
1       ST      0
2       JS      80
3       MA      NULL
```

I hope I have elaborated quite clearly what I want to achieve. Please give me directions on how to achieve this. I am new to SQL and learning bits and bytes of RDBMS. Thank you in advance.

Ritesh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I accomplished this with a recursive CTE to calculate the running balances, and then an outer apply to get the final result.

I understand from your sample output, that at the moment a user's balance reaches 0, you start over calculating their balance with the debit - credit, rather than continuing the formula previous balance - credit. That's what this CTE accomplishes.

```
WITH rk AS (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY custid ORDER BY transid) rn, transid, custid, tdate, dtamt, cramt
            FROM   tbl_transaction)
    ,bl AS (SELECT rk.rn, rk.transid, rk.custid, rk.tdate, rk.dtamt, rk.cramt, rk.dtamt - rk.cramt balance
            FROM   rk
            WHERE  rk.rn = 1
            UNION ALL
            SELECT rk2.rn, rk2.transid, rk2.custid, rk2.tdate, rk2.dtamt, rk2.cramt
                  ,CASE WHEN bl.balance = 0 THEN rk2.dtamt - rk2.cramt ELSE bl.balance - rk2.cramt END balance
            FROM   bl, rk rk2
            WHERE  bl.rn = rk2.rn - 1 and bl.custid = rk2.custid)
-- SELECT * FROM bl ORDER BY custid, transid
SELECT cc.custid, cc.NAME, xx.Balance
FROM   tbl_Customer cc
       OUTER APPLY (SELECT TOP 1 bl.Balance
                    FROM   bl
                    WHERE  bl.custid = cc.custid
                    ORDER  BY bl.rn DESC) xx
```

The uncommented select from the CTE returns the output as defined. You can switch the commenting after the CTE to see that that CTE returns the intermediate table exactly as you defined. (as of 2:35P)

Of course, addition and subtraction are commutative. Really, the final balance can be answered thus:

```
SELECT cc.custid, cc.NAME, xx.Balance
FROM   tbl_Customer cc
       OUTER APPLY (SELECT SUM(tt.dtamt) - SUM(tt.cramt) Balance
                    FROM   tbl_Transaction tt
                    WHERE  tt.custid = cc.custid) xx
```

This kind of query is bound to be long running.  You could try creating an indexed view on the aggregate in tbl_Transaction:

```
CREATE VIEW dbo.dv_TransactionTotals 
WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
SELECT tt.custid, SUM(tt.dtamt) - SUM(tt.cramt) Balance, COUNT_BIG(*) Transactions
FROM   dbo.tbl_Transaction tt -- assuming schema here
GROUP  BY tt.custid

CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX ixc_TransactionTotals ON dbo.dv_TransactionTotals (custid)
```

Expect this index to take a while to build, and realize its existence will have some impact on your inserts.  See http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc917715.aspx for more information. (Note the COUNT_BIG field is required by the index -- I always forget that until I try to run the index. Also note that the tables must be properly qualified by schema; I've assumed dbo as no other was provided.)

Aggregation awareness in SQL 2005 might cause it to use the view automatically, but I never trust that. You might also turn the query into a union of those with transactions and those without:

```
SELECT cc.custid, cc.NAME, tt.Balance
FROM   tbl_Customer cc
       INNER JOIN dv_TransactionTotals tt ON tt.custid = cc.custid
UNION  ALL
SELECT cc.custid, cc.NAME, NULL Balance
FROM   tbl_Customer cc
WHERE  cc.custid NOT IN (SELECT custid FROM dv_TransactionTotals tt WHERE tt.custid = cc.custid)
```

I do hope you wouldn't run this monster on production, as it is clearly a reporting concern. Indeed, were I faced with this problem, I would create (or tap into) a data warehouse, setup replication on the necessary tables, and create a process that would periodically add these data to fact tables.

Comment: I tried the query but it was taking a lot of time in execution and after a minute or so, it results in "Exhaustion" error. I have more than 2 million records in Transactions table. Could there be any optimized way>

Comment: Thank you guys for saving my neck. :)

Answer (score 2):

The following should work, I am not 100% on the middle query to get each intermediate value, but I believe it should work.

Setup the resultset:

```
SELECT *,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY CustId ORDER BY TransDate) AS TransactionOrderNum
INTO #TransactionOrder
FROM tbl_Transaction
```

I believe that this cross apply should work, but I admit I am not 100%:

```
SELECT #TransactionOrder.*, CustomerSum AS Balance
FROM #TransactionOrder
    CROSS APPLY
    (
        SELECT SUM(
                CASE WHEN TransactionOrderNum = 1 THEN DtAmt - CrAmt
                ELSE (CrAmt * -1) END
            ) AS CustomerSum 
        FROM #TransactionOrder AS Summation
        WHERE Summation.TransactionOrderNum<= #TransactionOrder.TransactionOrderNum
            AND Summation.CustId = #TransactionOrder.CustId
        GROUP BY CustId
    ) AS SumValues
```

This definitely should work towards giving you the final amount:

```
SELECT tbl_Customer.CustId, tbl_Customer.Name, SUM
(
    CASE WHEN TransactionOrderNum = 1 THEN DtAmt - CrAmt
    ELSE (CrAmt * -1) END
) AS CustomerSum 
FROM tbl_Customer
    LEFT JOIN #TransactionOrder
        ON tbl_Customer.CustId = #TransactionOrder.CustId
GROUP BY tbl_Customer.CustId, tbl_Customer.Name
```

You could use a [CTE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766.aspx), also:

```
WITH TransactionOrder AS
(
    SELECT *,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY CustId ORDER BY TransDate) 
            AS TransactionOrderNum
    FROM tbl_Transaction
)
SELECT TransactionOrder.*, CustomerSum AS Balance
FROM TransactionOrder
    CROSS APPLY
    (
        SELECT SUM(
                CASE WHEN TransactionOrderNum = 1 THEN DtAmt - CrAmt
                ELSE (CrAmt * -1) END
            ) AS CustomerSum 
        FROM TransactionOrder AS Summation
        WHERE Summation.TransactionOrderNum<= TransactionOrder.TransactionOrderNum
            AND Summation.CustId = TransactionOrder.CustId
        GROUP BY CustId
    ) AS SumValues
```

Now, if this is one flow of data, then you could just store the interim select into a temp table and pick the max(TransactionOrderNum) row for each of the custid's

Add this between the `select` and `from` in the balance-as-you-go query

```
INTO #BalanceAsYouGo
```

Then the final query becomes more like this:

```
SELECT tbl_Customer.CustId, tbl_Customer.Name, #BalanceAsYouGo.Balance
FROM tbl_Customer
    LEFT JOIN #BalanceAsYouGo
        ON tbl_Customer.CustId = #BalanceAsYouGo.CustId
    LEFT JOIN 
    (
         SELECT CustId, MAX(TransactionOrderNum) AS MaxTransNum
         FROM #BalanceAsYouGo
         GROUP BY CustId
    ) AS FinalBalance
        ON FinalBalance.CustId = #BalanceAsYouGo.CustId
            FinalBalance.MaxTransNum = #BalanceAsYouGo.TransactionOrderNum
GROUP BY tbl_Customer.CustId, tbl_Customer.Name
```

Comment: Do I need to create temporary table #TransactionOrder? Will it be good for performance? Currently tbl_Customer has around 1000 records and tbl_Transaction has more than 2000000 records. For me the last resultset is most important right now.
Thank you for your help. I'll try your code and let you know.

Comment: You could use a CTE, but I dont know that it will gain you much in performance. I will add how this would be done

Comment: This has been updated to use a CTE, as well as pointing out that you do not need to recalculate the SUM again if you are running this all in the same SQL flow. That should help